# Building .NET WCF service for iPhone with authentication

Tags: iphone, .net, wcf

Trying to create a very simple restful WCF service which will serve data to an iPhone application.

Would like to utilise basic authentication of some kind, most likely username / password or a token of some sort.

Having a few issues finding any good documentation around the subject so any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's interested, I resolved this with the following:

In web.config under system.servicemodel:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="default">
            <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Your.ServiceAuthorizationManager"></serviceAuthorization>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
    <service name="Your.WCF.Service" behaviorConfiguration="default">
</services>
```

Then in your manager handling (Your.ServiceAuthorizationManager class) you have access to the request in the operation context, can authorize and return true if authorized and false if not.

```
public class Your.ServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        // Validate request here...

        return true;
    }
}
```

- Obviously copying and pasting this code won't work, you'll need to edit in a few places.

Hope it helps someone!