# Can an iOS app consume a WCF service using wsHttpBinding?

Tags: ios, wcf, wshttpbinding

I am building a WCF service now, that has a wsHttpBinding endpoint.

The client for now is WPF.

I would like to know if in the future, it would be possible to develop an iOS application that would be able to connect to my WCF service endpoint (it has to be wsHttpBinding, because I need security, reliability and ordered messaging).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually not, but it depends how you configure the WSHttpBinding. If you use any kind of message level security almost surely you will not be able to call it from iOS. I'm saying almost b/c iOS supports sendins soap over http and some of the scenarios (useranme) are not complex so in theory you could manually push them to the soap. But for the most part basicHttpBinding is better (and also prefer transport security).

Comment: I use 'CustomUserNamePasswordValidator'. Can you refer me to any articles that show how iOS can support sending SOAP over HTTP with the USERNAME scenario ?

Comment: I don't know of such article. What you should do is get some sample working message (e.g. build a working WCF client and use WCF logging or Fiddler to get it). Then you will need to create the same xml in iOS. This should not be hard - if you will set requireTimestamp to false in WCF (required customhttpbinding) it will even be easier.

Comment: Thanks Yaron (Israeli ?). Do you have a reference for 'creating XML for WCF in iOS app' for me ?

Comment: Hi John - I'm not an iOS developer myself, but some ways to create xml may be by concatanating strings or preffered by a library like this http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml. It also depend how you plan to create the actual soap, if you do it manually or via some library - I wrote about it here http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2010/09/wcf-on-iphone.html. Once you know your iOS landscape I can help you with any ws-security username related tasks. And yep, I'm from Israel.

Comment: As far as I know iOS doesn't have a SOAP stack so it will be rolling everything by hand one way or another. If you are just using transport security and the WS-* stuff turned off then you basically have BasicHttpBinding

Answer (score 4):

I researched a bit and from what I found, it is not possible (at least not easily), please inform me if there is a way

For security I followed the following solution, which fulfills my needs:
[Building .NET WCF service for iPhone with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221399/building-net-wcf-service-for-iphone-with-authentication)

Comment: I am using 'UserNamePasswordValidator', cause I need to validate the username and password against a database (I was told to do this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261228/wcf-authenticate-client-with-database) and it works well with WPF clients. What is the difference between the method of using a 'CustomUsernamePasswordValidator' and the method you have just posted here?