# How to consume WCF Service with WSHttpBinding in iOS application?

Tags: ios, wshttpbinding

Can we consume `WSHTTPBinding` service in iPhone Application?
I am trying to consume such a service, but I am getting status code 415. I also tried it with all different possible ways but getting same error code everytime.

In one article, I read that, to consume `WSHttpBinding` services, .NET 3.0 is required on client side.

So is there any way to consume the `WSHttpBinding` service in iPhone applications or its not possible.Need some guidance on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a response to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583414/can-an-ios-app-consume-a-wcf-service-using-wshttpbinding).

Short answer is "Usually not, but it depends how you configure the `WSHttpBinding`. `BasicHttpBinding` is better (and also prefer transport security)."

As I know the situation with iOS+WSHTTPBinding didn`t changed.